# Highchart ,display time in regular interval

Tags: highcharts

Im trying to display a simple graph with x axis as time and y axis as points.

But, the time values seems to be off a little bit. The distance between 2017-10-06 &&= 2017-10-07 is smaller than 2017-10-10 & 2017-10-11 even though they are at same 1 day gap. How do I fix this?

[image]

Here is my code

```
function generatepointgraph(data) {
    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: true
        }
    });
    Highcharts.chart('points-container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                second: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M:%S',
                minute: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
                hour: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
                day: '%Y-%m-%d',
                week: '%Y-%m-%d',
                month: '%Y-%m',
                year: '%Y'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weighted pts'
            }
        },
        scrollbar: {
            showFull: true
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Pts vs time',
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Points',
            data: data,
            step: true,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide your data, so that we can reproduce this issue. Also I suppose that there's some inconsistency, because the image that you attached is a **Highstock** chart (it has the **navigator** and is created via `Highcharts.stockChart` constructor), but in the code you use standard **Highcharts** constructor (`Highcharts.chart`).